# Linq to XML Error

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a problem with my Linq to XML query:

```
 var q = (from f in xmlLang.Element("lang").Elements("page")
               where (string)f.Attribute("id") == "home"
               select f.Element(LangElement).Value.ToString()).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
```

The XML looks like this,

```
<lang>
  <page id="home">
     <hello>Hello!</hello>
  </page>
  ...
</lang>
```

I get this error:   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You probably should also show us the assignment of the xmlLang variable. Otherwise I see little chance for anyone to answer your question by anything but pure guessing luck.

Comment: You can probably use First instead of Take(1).SingleOrDefault()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's `f.Element(LangElement)` supposed to do?

- You haven't defined `LangElement` anywhere in this snippet.
- For readability, I'd give `f` a more descriptive name (say, `langpage` or something).
- `.Take(1).SingleOrDefault()` is more succinctly put as `.FirstOrDefault()`

This code works:

```
var xmlLang = XDocument.Parse(@"
<lang>
  <page id=""home"">
    <hello>Hello!</hello>
  </page>
  ...
</lang>");

var q = (from langpage in xmlLang.Element("lang").Elements("page")
         where langpage.Attribute("id").Value == "home"
         select langpage.Element("hello").Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

If xmlLang is loaded differently, your query may not be matching any element "lang" - hence the exception.

Comment: LangElement = string, like "hello".